How to repair a Koto with separation from the baseboard?
I purchased an older used Koto where the base board in the middle of the instrument has separated from the main body. On either ends of the Koto, the base board is still attached, it's just bent away in the middle.
How would you fix this? Would a ton of wood glue and some time in clamps be sufficient? I'm unsure what causes a Koto to get in this state in the first place, aside from possibly string tension over the years or improper storage.

EDIT:
I talked to the seller and they think this happened during shipping. They're trying to get it refunded via insurance.

Under speculation about why: It might be that storage without string tension is to blame. If I understand the picture, it looks like all the bridges have been removed. I have no idea, but I would figure the instrument is built to withstand their pressure, and maybe has a bit of arch built in, and with them removed it sprang up. General rule of thumb for long-term storage is to reduce but not eliminate tension.

That would make sense from the direction of the bend. Though, from everything I've read and watched, the bridges are only supposed to be used when frequently playing the Koto, in order to prevent the strings from stretching too much. The strings without the bridges installed have enough tension in them to play notes when plucked.

Why'd you delete your answer? I don't know that I'd try it, or even that I'd recommend it to others, but it seems worthwhile to report that it worked, at least well enough for your current needs.

I hid it to protect myself during the price negotiation period, it should be safe now so I unhid it.

For instrument making often different glues are used (e.g. hide glue). These are reversible by heat and humidity. But this also means that especially in warm humid climate the joint may come loose. If your instrument is of little quality you can of course try fixing it yourself. Else I think it might be reasonable to find someone with experience in instrument making (although many professionals will not work on instruments they do not have experience with). But I’m quite positive that an experienced luthier or violin maker will do at least a better job at fixing this than just filling it with glue. Of course optimally you’d have someone with experience in Kotos check the instrument. But then, depending on where you are it will be hard to find such a person.

@user1817467 If you can't find the right person locally, you might consider shipping it, with appropriate packaging and insurance. I once had a specialized violin bow "surgery" that I had to mail to a specialist. But koto is common enough that there might be qualified people in many cities across the world.

I don't know how to judge the quality of a Koto. I can only say it sounds nice and the price was quite high, especially due to being an oversized import. You make a good point about the materials used (type of glue) possibly making a difference. I'm going to at least research the manufacturing process to make more sense of it. I've already looked at repair shops, and there's absolutely nothing near me. Not sure I want to pay the cost to ship this thing again.

So I did some research on how Kotos are made. It seems the base board is simply glued on to the main body with a hide glue after the main body is carved. So, I bought some hide glue and shoved as much as I could in the cracks by using a small wooden wedge. The instructions say you're supposed to sand and clean the surface first, but unfortunately there's not enough room in the crack to do that sort of cleaning work.
I then clamped it together with rope, wooden blocks, and used wedges to tighten the rope. This is following the method I saw they use when they create these from scratch.

EDIT:
The glue has dried now and I removed the clamps. This worked quite well. The crack is sealed. The instrument sounds the same. There's no additional damage caused by the clamping process.
Looking at the wooden wedge I used to apply glue with, this hide glue seems to just fuse with the wood. It's impossible to remove. Yet it didn't stick at all to the plastic I set it on top of. It's interesting how a glue can be so picky to which type of surface it sticks to.
